# SQL: How to return month and character corresponding to an ordinal number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I return the following result? I understand how to create the first column with a "connect by level" query.

For `lvl` between 1 and 12, how do I generate the corresponding month? For lvl between 1 and 24 (or whatever the "chosen" alphabet has), how do I generate the corresponding letter (lower-case character)?

```
lvl month   char
1   Jan     a
2   Feb     b
3   Mar     c
4   Apr     d
5   May     e
```

Comment: Not a clue what you are asking.

Comment: So, what do you need? The random numbers you know already (second column), so you don't need help with that. Do you want to know how to get the months (numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) corresponding to the `num` value, and the same for characters - in lower case?

Comment: @mathguy  Yes, I just want to get these points.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you want to know how to convert `level` to a month and to a character...

For the month: `to_char(to_date(level, 'mm'), 'Mon')`

For the letter it's more complicated. In a language like `C`, a `char` is just a number and you can do "char arithmetic" pretty much like you do date arithmetic in Oracle. However, you can't do character arithmetic in Oracle, or at least not easily.

The best way would be to create a table of "ordinal number, corresponding character" (in whatever language you need it to be) and do an inner join. There are other solutions but they depend on explicit mappings in character sets; not recommended!

However, if you just want to use ASCII letters, you can use the `chr()` and `ascii()` functions and arithmetic. Example:

```
select level                                  as lvl, 
       to_char( to_date(level, 'mm'), 'Mon' ) as mnth,
       chr( ascii('a') + level - 1 )          as character
from dual 
connect by level <= 5;



       LVL MNTH         CHARACTER
---------- ------------ ---------
         1 Jan          a
         2 Feb          b
         3 Mar          c
         4 Apr          d
         5 May          e
```

Comment: I suddenly thought of maybe you can use this http://debugguru.blogspot.jp/2011/11/searching-unicode-characters-in-oracle.html